# How can I optimize this Email list powershell script

Tags: windows, powershell

How can I configure this script so that I can repeat this mailing process for multiple addresses eg Europe, Asia without copying the code multiple times?

For example could I do something like this?:

`IF $keyword "Europe"` found `THEN
$europe`

`$europe =` Does the Europe stuff

`THEN`

`IF $keyword "Asia"` found `THEN
$asia`

etc.

**Here is my code:**

```
   # Email Automation

    #Defines Directory
    $dir = "C:\Users\user\Desktop\myfolder"
    #Sets STMP server
    $SMTPServer = "10.0.0.1"
    #Declares todays time and formats
    $Time = (Get-Date).ToString('MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt')

    # Europe # 
    #Declares the keyword used to find List
    $keywordEur = "Europe" 

     #Searches dir for list , formats 
    $AttachmentEur = Get-ChildItem -Path $dir -Filter "*$keywordEur*" -Recurse
    $AttachmentNameEur = $AttachmentEur.BaseName

    #Defines mailing list
    $FromEur = "me@email.com"
    $ToEur = "you@europeemail.com"
    $CcEur = "him@email.com", "her@email.com"
    $SubjectEur = "$AttachmentName @ $Time"
    $BodyEur = "Please find attached the file needed for Europe. 

    Regards,
    Me
    "

    #Actions Email
    Send-MailMessage -From $FromEur -To $ToEur -CC $CcEur -Subject         $SubjectEur -Body $BodyEur -SmtpServer $SMTPServerEur -Attachments         $AttachmentEur.FullName

    # Asia # 
    #Declares the keyword used to find List
    $keywordAs = "Asia" 

     #Searches dir for list , formats 
    $AttachmentAs = Get-ChildItem -Path $dir -Filter "*$keywordAs*" -Recurse
    $AttachmentNameAs = $AttachmentAs.BaseName

    #Defines mailing list
    $FromAs = "me@email.com"
    $ToAs = "you@asiaemail.com"
    $CcAs = "him@email.com", "her@email.com"
    $SubjectAs = "$AttachmentNameAs @ $Time"
    $BodyAs = "Please find attached the file needed for Asia. 

    Regards,
    Me
    "

    #Actions Email
    Send-MailMessage -From $FromAs -To $ToAs -CC $CcAs -Subject $SubjectAs         -Body $BodyAs -SmtpServer $SMTPServerAs -Attachments $AttachmentAs.FullName
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how you could repeat it with a `ForEach` loop and an object built with two hashtables for the regions:

```
# Email Automation

#Defines Directory
$dir = "C:\Users\user\Desktop\myfolder"
#Sets STMP server
$SMTPServer = "10.0.0.1"
#Declares todays time and formats
$Time = (Get-Date).ToString('MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt')

$Europe = @{            
    Name = 'Asia'
    From = "me@email.com"
    To = "you@email.com"
    Cc = "him@email.com", "her@email.com"
}

$Asia = @{  
    Name = 'Asia'          
    From = "me@email.com"
    To = "you@email.com"
    Cc = "him@email.com", "her@email.com"
}

$Regions = @()
$Regions += New-Object PSObject -Property $Asia
$Regions += New-Object PSObject -Property $Europe

ForEach ($Region in $Regions) {

    #Searches dir for list , formats 
    $Attachment = Get-ChildItem -Path $dir -Filter "*$($Region.name)*" -Recurse
    $AttachmentName = $Attachment.BaseName

    $Subject = "$AttachmentName @ $Time"
    $Body = "Please find attached the file needed for $($Region.name). 

    Regards,
    Me
    "
    #Actions Email
    Send-MailMessage -From $Region.From -To $Region.To -CC $Region.Cc -Subject $Subject -Body $Body -SmtpServer $SMTPServer -Attachments $Attachment.FullName
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help so far but I also need to send the email to different email addresses based on the keyword

Comment: Is it always the same set of addresses for each keyword?

Comment: No its different To and Cc addresses for each keyword, does this mean i should use IF statements based on each keyword?

Comment: I've amended my answer with a suggested solution that might be tidier than a lot of `if` statements.

Comment: Thank you! Works perfect :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is. Since the keywords themselves are the only thing that seems to change, put your keywords in an array and wrap the entire thing in a loop:

```
# Email Automation

#Define Directory
$dir = "C:\Users\user\Desktop\myfolder"
#Set STMP server
$SMTPServer = "10.0.0.1"
#Declare todays time and formats
$Time = (Get-Date).ToString('MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt')

#Define mailing list
$From = "me@email.com"
$To = "you@email.com"
$Cc = "him@email.com", "her@email.com"

#Declares the keywords used to find attachments
$keywords = 'Europe','Asia'

foreach($keyword in $keywords){
    #Searches dir for list , formats 
    $Attachment = Get-ChildItem -Path $dir -Filter "*$keyword*" -Recurse
    $AttachmentName = $Attachment.BaseName

    $Subject = "$AttachmentName @ $Time"
    $Body = "Please find attached the file needed for $keyword. 

    Regards,
    Me
    "

    #Actions Email
    Send-MailMessage -From $From -To $To -CC $Cc -Subject $Subject -Body $Body -SmtpServer $SMTPServer -Attachments $Attachment.FullName
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help so far but I also need to send the email to different email addresses based on the keyword